# Lose hlsearch when using with vim-fuzzysearch

Tags: vimscript, highlight

I'm using this plugin: [vim-fuzzysearch](https://github.com/ggVGc/vim-fuzzysearch/blob/master/plugin/fuzzysearch.vim).

When I have long file (I need to press `ctrl-f/ctrl-b` to scroll)

Steps to produces:

```
1. Turn on `hlsearch` + vim-fuzzysearch and search for a keyword
2. Immediately press `ctrl-f` to scroll down
3. Observe highlight lost of matched patterns on the file (like nohlsearch is set)
4. Press `n` and re-try `ctrl-f/ctrl-b`, now hlsearch on matched patterns recovered.
```

If I don't use vim-fuzzyearch then there's no issue, I observe no highlight lost of matched patterns.

Comment: Are you the person who opened the issue on the plugin's github site? https://github.com/ggVGc/vim-fuzzysearch/issues/3 Don't think the question here is needed. In fact, the only response here might have been "open an issue at the plugin site". :)

Comment: @BLayer: :) Someone might have better experience with vimscript than me and may have useful help. :)

Comment: Actually, you'd probably be better off finding an alternative. That project was active for about 8 months in 2015 and has been untouched since.

Comment: @BLayer Do you have any suggestions for alternatives? I can’t find better one with similar functionality.

Comment: I don't know any offhand. Will reply if I think of one. Hopefully someone else here knows of something.